# How to include this large table in beamer frame

Tags: tables, beamer

How can I include this large table in a beamer frame? Can anyone please help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,natbib,pgfgantt}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow, bm,color}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum,booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx, float,hyperref, subfigure}
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,linkcolor = blue,anchorcolor = blue,citecolor = blue,filecolor = blue,urlcolor = blue}
\usepackage[top=1.2in,left=1.2 in,right=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{pdflscape,array,booktabs}
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}


    \begin{sidewaystable}
        \caption{Simulation results }
        \vskip 0.4cm
        \centering
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{2.2cm}lcccccccccccccccccccc}

                \hline
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Settings}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{perfect}& &\multicolumn{4}{c}{10\% values} & &\multicolumn{4}{c}{30\% values} & &\multicolumn{4}{c}{50\% values}     \\

                \cmidrule{2-3}  \cmidrule{5-5} \cmidrule{7-10} \cmidrule{12-15} \cmidrule{17-20}
                Model & $\beta$          &&   &  & & s1 & s2 & s3 & s4& & s1 & s2 & s3 & s4& &s1 & s2 & s3 & s4\\

                \midrule
                \multicolumn{13}{l}{Bias}                                \\
                &    0        & 336  &       &-0.006 & & 0.005  & 0.005  & 0.005  & 0.011  & &
                -0.006 & -0.006 & -0.006 & 0     & &
                0.008 & 0.003  & 0.004  & 0.011 \\
                &    0.5      &  336 &       & -0.004 & & 0.004  & -0.007 & 0.003  & 0.012 & & 
                0.001  & -0.031 & 0.001  & -0.005  & &
                0.01  & -0.046 & 0.011  & -0.007 \\
                &    1        &  84  &       & 0.012  & & -0.004 & -0.024 & -0.003 & 0.005 & &
                0.021  & -0.046 & 0.019  & 0.004 & &
                0.038 & -0.071 & 0.035  & -0.071 \\
                \multicolumn{13}{l}{}   \\ 

                \multicolumn{13}{l}{MSE}                                \\
                &    0        &  336 &        & 0.026  & & 0.028  & 0.027  & 0.028  & 0.03  & &
                0.04   & 0.037  & 0.041  & 0.035 & &
                0.052 & 0.044  & 0.052  & 0.053 \\
                &    0.5      &  336 &       & 0.023  & & 0.026  & 0.025  & 0.026  & 0.028 & & 
                0.034  & 0.032  & 0.035  & 0.034 & &
                0.048 & 0.042  & 0.046  & 0.051 \\
                &    1        & 84   &       & 0.103  & & 0.098  & 0.095  & 0.098  & 0.114 & &
                0.142  & 0.125  & 0.142  & 0.156 & &
                0.195 & 0.161  & 0.194  & 0.2   \\



                \multicolumn{13}{l}{}   \\ 

                \multicolumn{13}{l}{Coverage}                                \\
                &    0        &   336  &      & 95.2   & & 94.9   & 94.9   & 94.7   & 93.4  & &
                93.8   & 94.4   & 92.6   & 92.7 & &
                94.6  & 95.8   & 94.3   & 90.2 \\
                &    0.5      &   336  &       & 95.5   & & 95.4   & 95.9   & 94.9   & 93.7 & & 
                94.4   & 94.9   & 94.8   & 92.8 & &
                95.2  & 95.6   & 95.1   & 88.6 \\
                &    1        &   84   &      & 94.5   & & 96.6   & 96.8   & 96.3   & 94.8 & &
                96     & 95.7   & 95.4   & 92.7 & &
                96.2  & 96.7   & 96.6   & 92.2 \\

                \bottomrule                         \\
        \end{tabular}}%

    \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, you kind of have a (brute force) solution in your code already: `\resizebox`. Of course, the numbers will be too small, and a big table like that is possibly not ideal for a presentation, but if you really need it, just change `sidewaystable` to `table` and plonk it in a `frame`.

Comment: Don't include large table! instead of it show results in form of graphs or make summary of table.

Comment: *Simple solution:* **(1)** Save the table as a PDF file (single page). **(2)** Include the table like a normal graphic in beamer -- maybe you need the `crop`  option of the `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner You forgot: (3) hand out opera glasses to the audience and (4) apologies for the tiny font and cramped table.

Comment: @samcarter Haha :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get rid of (a) all blank columns, (b) all blank rows, and (c) other space-inefficient constructs (of which there are quite a few). To enhance legibility, you should think about aligning the numbers on their respective decimal markers, as is done in the following code.

For a `beamer` document, don't use a `table` environment, and place what would be the table's caption in the frame title.

Even with all of these adjustments, the table will be at the lower limit of readability. Do consider simplifying the table. E.g., are some of the 16 [!] columns not entirely essential? If so, don't show them!

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}} % automatic math mode version of "r" column type
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt
\frametitle{Simulation results}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{} l lr *{13}{R} @{}}     
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{Settings} & \text{perfect}
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{10\% values} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{30\% values} 
&\multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{50\% values} \\
\cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-12} \cmidrule(l){13-16}
Model & $\beta$ & & & \mc{s1} & \mc{s2} & \mc{s3} & \mc{s4} 
                    & \mc{s1} & \mc{s2} & \mc{s3} & \mc{s4} 
                    & \mc{s1} & \mc{s2} & \mc{s3} & \mc{s4}\\
\midrule
Bias\\ % no need for "\multicolumn{13}{l}{Bias}" ...
&    0  & 336  & -0.006 &
   0.005 & 0.005  & 0.005  & 0.011  & -0.006 & -0.006 & -0.006 & 0.000  & 0.008  & 0.003  & 0.004  & 0.011 \\
&    0.5&  336 & -0.004 &
   0.004 & -0.007 & 0.003  & 0.012  & 0.001  & -0.031 & 0.001  & -0.005 & 0.010  & -0.046 & 0.011  & -0.007 \\
&    1   &  84 & 0.012  &
  -0.004 & -0.024 & -0.003 & 0.005  & 0.021  & -0.046 & 0.019  &  0.004 & 0.038  & -0.071 & 0.035  & -0.071 \\
\addlinespace
MSE\\
&    0  &  336 & 0.026 &
   0.028  & 0.027  & 0.028  & 0.03  & 0.040  & 0.037  & 0.041  & 0.035 & 0.052  & 0.044  & 0.052  & 0.053 \\
&    0.5&  336 & 0.023 &
    0.026  & 0.025  & 0.026  & 0.028 & 0.034  & 0.032  & 0.035  & 0.034 & 0.048  & 0.042  & 0.046  & 0.051 \\
&    1  & 84   & 0.103 &
   0.098  & 0.095  & 0.098  & 0.114 & 0.142  & 0.125  & 0.142  & 0.156 & 0.195  & 0.161  & 0.194  & 0.200 \\
\addlinespace
Coverage\\
&    0  &  336 & 95.2  &
   94.9  & 94.9   & 94.7   & 93.4  & 93.8  & 94.4   & 92.6   & 92.7 & 94.6  & 95.8   & 94.3   & 90.2 \\
&    0.5&  336 & 95.5  &
   95.4  & 95.9   & 94.9   & 93.7 & 94.4  & 94.9   & 94.8   & 92.8 & 95.2  & 95.6   & 95.1   & 88.6 \\
&    1  &   84 & 94.5  &
   96.6  & 96.8   & 96.3   & 94.8 & 96.0  & 95.7   & 95.4   & 92.7 & 96.2  & 96.7   & 96.6   & 92.2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```